# Automating incoming email attachments from a specific email addresses with powershell

Tags: powershell

I need to be able to save attachments that are coming into a company mailbox into specific files determined by the address for the sender.

Through google and some trial and error I've produced the below but it is saving all the attachments in my inbox into all the test files.

I'm using powershell and have hit a bit of a wall with this, can anyone help?

```
$o = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$n = $o.GetNamespace("MAPI")
$inbox=$n.GetDefaultFolder(6)
$filepathA = "C:\Users\User\Documents\TEST1Folder"
$filepathB = "C:\Users\User\Documents\TEST2Folder"
$filepathC = "C:\Users\User\Documents\TEST3Folder"

$inbox.Items | foreach {
    If($_.sender = "*mail.com"){
        $_.attachments | foreach{
            $_.saveasfile((Join-Path $filepathA $_.filename))
        }
    }    
    If($_.sender = "*mail.com"){
        $_.attachments | foreach{
            $_.saveasfile((Join-Path $filepathB $_.filename))
        }
    } 
    If($_.sender = "*mail.com"){
        $_.attachments | foreach{
            $_.saveasfile((Join-Path $filepathc $_.filename))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There were several unmatched parentheses and curly braces in your code. Review and try out. Next time do proper indentation yourself to catch obvious flaws.

Comment: Looking at the code, why do you have the very same if 3 times? From this it's clear that the attachments are copied 3 times. Vary the email addresses and take a look at `Get-Help about_Comparison_Operators`

Comment: `=` is used for setting a value, you would use `-eq` for checking for an exact match. But you actually want to use `-like` for a wildcard match: `$_.sender -like "*mail.com"`